# convert curl command to get token (api call) to python request

Tags: python, json, curl, request

I am trying to get an API query into python. The command is:

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {reference_token}" https://{mywebsite-url}/accounts/
```

it gives some JSON data.I need a script to do this task and the token key is variable so I am using one more request to get token which is saved in get_token variable

so I tried this:

```
get_token = j['token']
Url = 'https://{mywebsite-url}/accounts/'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer + get_token'}
output = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

when I do print(headers) the output is:

```
{'Authorization': 'Bearer + get_token'}
```

I need my token value instead of get_token text, can anyone help?

Comment: How about ```headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + get_token}```?

Comment: Oh. thanks a lot! it working .